# Cubemap projection onto a sphere

Tags: materials, uv, shaders, texture-coordinates

I need to be able to generate texture coordinates on a sphere for cubemaps textures. But somehow I seem to fail in Blender to accomplish this.

See the image below as example cubemap.

[image: Cubemap example]

I am able to map the texture correctly in Unity by using an cubemap asset, but I am unable to reproduce this behavior in Blender.

Comment: On a sphere only or for env. texture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If on a spherical mesh, you can start with a cube (rotate its UV to fit your map), then add:

- Subdivision modifier with *"simple"* algorithm (we don't want to smooth but just to give more geometry for the cast below)
- Cast to sphere modifier

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction -- could you share that blend file? Because I've been doing all day and somehow it keeps pinching the texture coords.

Comment: here you are... no pinch it seems but uneven resolution at poles.

Comment: Thanks! The *simple* division did the trick! This thingy cost me alot of hours :)